# How to control carousel using jQuery in typescript?

Tags: jquery, css, angular, typescript

I'm using typescript and angular 2 to build a single page website. I have a carousel on the top and I have also added a video in one of the slides in the carousel. I would like to pause the carousel if the user has hovered the mouse over the video.

Let me explain what I have done so far.

- Installed jQuery using NPM.
- Included bootstrap and jQuery CDN to the
  HTML.
- Imported jquery in .ts file.

Even after all this, I'm unable to control carousel using jQuery with the following method.

**In home.component.ts:(Outside class)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".video").mouseenter(function () {
            <any>$(this).carousel("pause");
    });

    $(".video").mouseleave(function () {
            <any>$(this).carousel("cycle");
    });
}
```

JQuery is working fine but it always shows an error:
***Property 'carousel' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.)***

How will I be able to accomplish this? Where have I gone wrong? Is there any alternative of doing this either using jQuery or using CSS only? I've checked out several suggestions online but couldn't find a working solution. Thank you.

Comment: did you import any definitions for the carousel plugin? I'm guessing it's a plugin.

Comment: @toskv It's just a bootstrap carousel https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp
I have not imported any definitions. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by adding

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

before starting the jQuery code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You must install the typing definitions for **bootstrap** for the compiler to know about them.

The npm for them can be found here package is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap).

You can also find more packages with types [here](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).

Comment: I have installed but still getting an error.
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (home.component.ts:118)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.handle (eval at webpackJsonp.355.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:14), <anonymous>:3:13760)...`